# Supplement for std::less in Python

Tags: python, comparison

I am a Python noob, but with good C++ experience. I am trying to write some code, where I would like to use `<` and `>` functions based on some conditions.

The best way to do it, seemed like making a function pointer and initializing it based on some conditions. I know I can write my own `less` and `greater than` functions. And no, a simple Google search doesn't tell you the answer.

But, is there a predefined function in Python, like `std::less` and `std::greater`?

Comment: You can still use lambda.

Comment: Look at [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

Comment: @C.Nivs Looks like exactly, what I needed. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, C.Nivs, pointed in comments this can be done by using `operator` in Python.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html